# Search in Bounding Boxes and Locations

Tags: spatial-database, database

Description of the problem (what I need):

I have a set of bounding boxes (maybe the actual data is a location[longitude, latitude] in which case the bounding box will have identical corners). I have a search box (it is a bounding box too). Now I want to find which bounding boxes in my set intersect with my search box.

Question: Which databases/tools (I prefer open source ones and among them I prefer free ones) can do this?

Note: Currently I am using an in-memory RTree that I have developed. But my data is increasing and maintaining it; is becoming hard.

Comment: POSTGIS with postgres (ST_INTERSECT) http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html